# Firebase passing query promise result

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise

I'm struggling to implement a Firebase query promise where I can pass the resulting HTML into another function for use.

I have a Firebase query that is retrieving values from a node in the database, then creates some HTML using it:

```
   function getElem() {
      var query = firebase.database().ref('thumbnails/' + key);
      query.once('value').then(function(childSnapshot) {
         var link = childSnapshot.child('/link').val();

         //other database stuff...

         return link;
   }).then(function(link){
         //make some boring HTML
         var elem = document.createElement('div');
         //use link value as data attribute
         elem.dataset.link = link;

         //other data setting stuff...

         return elem;
       })
   }
```

`getElem` is then called inside `itemElements()`, my function that collects `elems` and appends them to my grid layout:

```
  function itemElements() {
      // add grid items
      var elems = [getElem(), getElem(), getElem()]; //get three elements
      // make jQuery object
      var $elems = $( elems );
      $grid.append( $elems );
  };
```

Since `getElem()`is returning a promise, with a resolved value, and not the value itself, `itemElement()`is trying to append promise objects to the grid -- which isn't very helpful. I understand vaguely that promises are async and so I can't just demand the return value, but how I do I go about ensuring `elem`is being returned from `getElem()` for `itemElement()`to use once the promises are resolved?

Comment: `Since getElem()is returning a promise` - no, it isn't, there is no return value in `getElem` function, it returns `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle the async aspect of the Promises. Try this:

```
function getElem() {
  return firebase.database().ref('...').once('value').then(function(link) {
    // ...
    return elem;
  });
}

function itemElements() {
  return Promise.all([getElem(),getElem(),getElem()]).then(function(elems) {
    var $elems = $(elems);
    $grid.append($elems);
  });
}
```

Note that in `getElem()` you need to **return** the Promise so that the async can chain together, and in `itemElements()` you need to call `Promise.all()` to wait for the async `getElem()` functions to resolve, then you can use the result.

Comment: Can't believe it's that simple -- worked a treat, thank you so much!